# How to set the Oauth Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, facebook-oauth

my project asp.net-mvc4 not come configured Oauth, I see that in the tutorials the projects have the folder App Start / Auth.Config - in my project does not have these files, as I start the project with this configuration? or how can I install? - I need to log into my facebook application

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before asking a question here please use Google.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012, in the MVC project selection dialog, select 'Internet Application.'  If you select any of the other types, you will have to create those files yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)

You can find some good examples with it. Take a look at the samples [source code](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth)